# How to use multiple xmlparsers in swift at the same time?

Tags: swift, xml, xcode, xml-parsing

In Swift. When I use xmlparser to render data for ONE intance it works fine, but if I try to render two different xml data sets it is not working. As I understand the xmlparser is synchronious so this will mess things up for the second xmlparser call. So how can I render xml data for two different datasets at the same time (or after each other)?

This is how I render one of my datasets which works fine. I include XMLParserDelegate:

```
var xmlParser: XMLParser!

self.xmlParser = XMLParser(data: HelperController.sharedInstance.XMLDataObject!)
self.xmlParser.delegate = self
self.xmlParser.parse()

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    eName = elementName
    if elementName == "someName" { 
        //do something
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
    //var jalla = NSString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        //do something 
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    eName = ""
    if elementName == "someName" {
      //do something
    } 
}
```

But I need to render another XMLDataObject. How can I do this? If I add the second  xmlparsing to a new class and initialize it from there it will not enter didStartElement (since the first xmlParser is currently busy I guess).

EDIT:

I have tried a lot of different ways to add the second parser. The way I try it now is that I have the second parser in separate class like this:

```
class SomeClassViewController: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

var xmlParserSecondParser: XMLParser!
var eName: String = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func initializeSecondParser(){
    self.xmlParserSecondParser = XMLParser(data: 
                   HelperController.sharedInstance.XMLDataObjectSecond!)
    self.xmlParserSecondParser.delegate = self
    self.xmlParserSecondParser.parse()
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: 
      String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, 
      attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
         eName = elementName
         if elementName == "someName" { 
           //do something
         }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
       let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: 
       CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
         if (!data.isEmpty) {
          //do something 
         }
    }

   func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, 
       namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
          eName = ""
          if elementName == "someName" {
            //do something
          } 
   }
}
}
```

When I run the first parser I also call initializeSecondParser() but that does'nt work since didStartElement is never called.

```
let someClassViewController = SomeClassViewController();
someClassViewController.initializeSecondParser();
```

I have also tried to make the second call async but no luck:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  let someClassViewController = SomeClassViewController();
  someClassViewController.initializeSecondParser();
}
```

Comment: It's unclear. Could you show how you create your second parser? And could you clarify what part of the class/delegate methods?

Comment: @Larme I have added answer to your question below

Comment: Edit your question with that, not as an answer, since its not answering your question...

Comment: Yes, I would have done that, but the edit button was not visible yesterday. Now it is visible though and I have moved the text to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate correctly your parsers:

```
struct CustomParser: XMLParserDelegate {
    let xmlParser: XMLParser
    let ename: String = ""
    init(with data: Data) {
        xmlParser = XMLParser(data: data)
        xmlParser.delegate = self
    }
    
    // Here its returning the value you want
    var parsedResponse: ParsedResponse?
    func parse() -> ParsedResponse? {
        xmlParser.parse()
        return parsedResponse
    }
    // ParserDelegates
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        ...
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, 
       namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}



let parser1 = CustomParser(with: HelperController.sharedInstance.XMLDataObjectFirst!)
let parsed1 = parser1.parse()

let parser2 = CustomParser(with: HelperController.sharedInstance.XMLDataObjectSecond!)
let parsed2 = parser2.parse()
```

That's the way I'd recommend, since you separate correctly your parsing from `UIViewController`. You won't have big `UIViewController` that do the XML parsing, and much more...

You can use 2 parser still, but with little you've shown, it could be harder, is to check which `parser` it is in the delegate method, and act accordingly, but that's adds complexity and prone to error (forget something somewhere and break then everything):

```
var firstParser: XMLParser!
var firstEName: String = String()
var secondParser: XMLParser!
var secondEName: String = String()

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if parser == firstParser {
        firstEName = elementName
        if elementName == "someName" { 
           //do something
        }
    } else if parser == secondParser {
        secondEName = elementName
        if elementName == "someName" { 
           //do something
        }
    } else {
        //It's another parser, what to do?
    }
}
```

And do that check for each delegate method. So if you forget to do the check in one of the method, you might have weird results...

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked to check which parser is used in the delegate methods.